# Android studio audio stops playing when app is closed

Tags: java, android, audio, android-studio

I am making a audio player in my app. It is using a viewlist and all is working perfectly. I can start pause, next music stream. I am loading an url to play the music. When i close the app the music stops playing. I needed to continue playing. I have read something about audio focus. But i am not tally sure how to add it to the code. I have in my manifest the wake_lock.

I am pretty new to android so it is trail and error, but this one i just can't figure out. Also when i close the app and start it again when the music was playing and start it back up, the app crashes.

```
 public void controlMusicPlayer(String musicUrl) {

        final String playUrl = musicUrl;


        Log.d("Song url received:", playUrl);
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    playercontrol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);

                    new Player()
                     .execute(playUrl);
            playPause = true;

            Log.d("Play State:", "Starting song");

        } else {

            Log.d("Play State:", "Next song is being started");

            playPause = true;

            mediaPlayer.reset();

            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            playPause = false;

            new Player()
            .execute(playUrl);


        }

            }

       public View.OnClickListener pausePlay = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (!playPause) {

                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    if (intialStage)
                        new Player()
                                .execute(Urlmusic);
                    else {
                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                    playPause = true;
                } else {
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    playPause = false;
                }
            }
        };


    /**
     * preparing mediaplayer will take sometime to buffer the content so prepare it inside the background thread and starting it on UI thread.
     * @author piyush
     *
     */

    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean prepared;
            try {

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        intialStage = true;
                        playPause=false;
                        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("IllegarArgument", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progress.isShowing()) {
                progress.cancel();
            }
            Log.d("Prepared", "//" + result);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            intialStage = false;
        }

        public Player() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.progress.setMessage("Buffering...");
            this.progress.show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////// end music play list /////////////////////////////////////////
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you should use a service to play the audio instead of just doing it on activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you release the `mediaPlayer` in `onPause` method. This method is always called when you close the app. For more information google for [activity lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6rbi.png). So if you want your audio to continue playing when activity is paused - replace `onPause` method by `onDestroy` (this one is called when finish() is called.

Comment: i am going to have a look at this solution, it seems to make a whole lot of sense . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run A background service and play your audio(media player) in that service and you can use foreground notification to control the pause play or next etc from that notification

Comment: the thing is that the player will be used on all activities, i am not sure i can set the song information for all activites from the service. Plus i have to find a tutorial about using url streaming music.

Comment: U can use mediaplayer in activity but i would recommend background service for this task with a good looking notification also choisce is yours ..Well in your code you are using mediaplayer.setDatasource(url) so u dont need to find a tutorial about using url streaming music
You can get a lot of help from this sample  media player plus this music player have a good UI also
https://github.com/play/play-android